# Rendering an image at runtime in WinRT

Tags: png, rendering, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I found that WriteableBitmap.Render() is not supported in WinRT. Is there any other API for drawing bitmap images in Metro? I need to render some xaml-primitives (Rectangles, Circles, Paths, etc.) to png-image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed not supported yet. Your best bets are to either use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) or Direct2D.