# How can I use XamlUIPresenter?

Tags: image, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, direct3d

In WinRT we have new class "[XamlUIPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.xamluipresenter)". XamlUIPresenter enables presenting a visual tree on a Microsoft Direct3D surface. But there are not any demos or examples of using it. How I can use this class? How I can get Direct3D surface? Can I render and save png with help of XamlUIPresenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC that class is only available for use with Blend and whatever the documentation says - it is not available to apps going to the Windows Store. If you need a replacement for the WriteableBitmap.Render method - see my answer to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840835/rendering-an-image-at-runtime-in-winrt).